# Data not loading on the main page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have simple AngularJS application that reads data from JSON and displays it on the page. I also have a couple of filters to search for data. Now the problem that I am facing is that after i implemented the filter logic, the data is not being displayed on the page. it was showing before I incorporated filtering in my code.

the foll is the rendering:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Gze.jpg)

the foll is the error:

> angular.js:13236 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 0
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/filter/notarray?p0=0
>           at angular.js:68
>           at angular.js:19280
>           at fn (eval at  (angular.js:14086), :4:315)
>           at trackByIdExpFn (angular.js:28452)
>           at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:28509)
>           at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:16529)
>           at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16664)
>           at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
>           at done (angular.js:11266)
>           at completeRequest (angular.js:11464)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9965Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16682Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16928done @ angular.js:11266completeRequest @ angular.js:11464requestLoaded @ angular.js:11405

the foll is my JSON structure:

```
[    
  {
    "name": "George Eliot",
    "thoughts": ["thought 1", "thought 2", "thought 3"]   
  },

  {
    "name": "Nietzsche",
    "thoughts": ["thought 1", "thought 2", "thought 3"]    
  }    
]
```

the foll is my filter code in the view:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Enter Search Term</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="classifiedsFilter">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <label>Select a Master</label>
    <md-select ng-model="name">
        <md-option ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ name }}">  
        {{ name }} 
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="classifiedsFilter = ''; name = ''">Clear</md-button>
</md-input-container>
```

the foll is the code for the main content area in the view:

```
<md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-align="center" layout-wrap>
    <md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds track by $index | filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: name" flex-xs="100" flex-gt-sm="70">

    <md-card-content>
        <div class="classified-info">
            <h2 class="md-display-2">{{ classified.name }}</h2>
            <ul> 
                <li ng-repeat="thought in classified.thoughts track by $index">{{ thought }}</li>
            </ul>  
        </div>

        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

the foll is the controller:

```
(function(){
     "use strict";   
     angular
      .module("ngClassifieds")
      .controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope, $http, classifiedsFactory) {
        classifiedsFactory.getClassifieds().then(function(mastersdata) {   
            $scope.classifieds = mastersdata.data;
            $scope.names = getNames($scope.classifieds);
        });

        function getNames(classifieds) {    
            var names = [];
            angular.forEach(classifieds, function(item) {                                   
                        names.push(item.name);                  
            });

            return _.uniq(names);               
        }    
    });    
})();
```

Any help wld be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: i was just exploring my code.. and i find that when i remove `| filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: name`, the content loads and there is no error. what am i missing here?

Comment: Hi, you can't use 2 filter in same element...you have to create custom filter . [Custom Filter](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters)

Comment: i removed `track by $index` agst `classified in classifieds` and the data is loading without any errors. im just curious as to why this is coz before i implemented filter logic i had to incorporate `track by $index` to avoid ngdupes error.